# Can not push to git: git considers me to be other user for some reason

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

When I `git clone` my repo from github - everything is OK. Repo is downloaded, but when I try to push changes to the repo, git says:

```
ERROR: Permission to my_user_name/repo_name.git denied to other_user_name.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I try to push to my repo, but github considers me to be other user. How did this happened? (That guy belongs to my team - we work on a few projects together). And how to fix this?

When I do `ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com` - it says that `other_user_name` is authorized, not me! But when I do `ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@bitbucket.com` - it tells my name. How is that possible?

Comment: check if `$ git config --list | grep user` looks correct

Comment: it shows my user name and email :)

Comment: check if you are pushing to the correct remote. You can list your remotes using `git remote -v`

Comment: yes, remote is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've found the source of the problem.

In order to deploy one application to production, we use `ansible` and separate ssh-key to connect to the server. It turned out that that deploy key was the key of one member from our team. So after deploy that key remained in my system that caused problem when pushing to github, cause github selected the first key it found.

In order to remove all keys I simply had to run `ssh-add -D`. After that log in to `github` and `bitbucket` was done with my own default ssh-key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **ssh** key of the system in **your** github account on github.com.

Answer (score 0):

That might mean that you have an SSH key belonging to another user in your user profile.
One way, not the best solution is to use git clone with the http:// url instead of the git:// url of your repository.
This should enable you to push without restrictions (but git will ask you for user and password).

Then when this will work, you might will to enable ssh authentication.
For this, you can follow the [github's guide to ssh key authentication](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

P.S : to change your local repository url from http to ssh and vice and versa, please refer to this [github's guide](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

Comment: How can I have other user key in my user profile? I've tried to add my key - it says that key is already added.

Comment: Please add details to your post like the command you typed to add your SSH key and the error message you received. Did you tried https://help.github.com/articles/error-key-already-in-use/ ?

Comment: huh, funny. it says i'm other user... but whey i try to connect to `bitbucker.org` it says my user name. so for some reason only `github` considers me other person.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SSH and not HTTPS for authentication. You may be better off with HTTPS authentication instead....

I would add that you need to make sure you are set private on both ends.
If for some reason you are pushing from a public account, that is the response given when the project is listed as private. If both are public then anyone can post to a project.
Also, check your permissions.
You may have reset to 'read only'. 
Without Write permission on, you cannot push an update or new code.

Another option is to fork your fix and ask your partner to pull it and check it.

Personally, I prefer Subversion.